# View does not reflect the data from $http.get(inside an angularjs controller)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Im using AngularJS and I'm creating a controller which is connected to the view. This controller gets data from the server every 10secs and the idea is to display/show the data to the client. My controller is shown below.

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('clock-widget-directives', []);

    app.controller('ViewClockController', function($scope, $http, $interval){
        $scope.xyzFunc = function() {
            var viewAll = this;
            viewAll.widget = [];

            $http.get('/statistics/deviceClock').success(function(data) {
             {
                viewAll.widget = data;
                console.log(data);

                alert(  data[0].utctime + " " + data[0].timezone + " " + data[0].timezoneOffset + " " + data[0].summerTimeZone );
            });
        }

        $interval( function(){ $scope.xyzFunc();}, 10000);

    });

})();
```

Using the controller above, I want to achieve my goal but the view doesn't display the data. I've already done my research, some article says it needs $apply but since I'm using $interval and not the javascript method setInterval() I do not need to call this.

Could you tell me what's wrong with the code above? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post HTML code?

Comment: Why are you using `viewAll` as a roundabout way to refer to `$scope`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a $scope variable outside *xyzFunc*, bind this variable, then set it's value from $http callback. Since you use angular's $http you do not have to worry about `apply`.

Added the code for better visualization:

```
app.controller('ViewClockController', function($scope, $http, $interval){
    $scope.viewAll = this;
    $scope.viewAll.widget = [];
    $scope.xyzFunc = function(){    
        $http.get('/statistics/clock').success(function(data) {
            $scope.viewAll.widget = data;
        });
    }

    $interval( function(){ 
        $scope.xyzFunc();
    }, 10000);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

this is because the angularJs digest cycle had finished by the time the response had come asynchronously so angular doesn't repaint the view with the new data .

try using the below code in the success callback after `viewAll.widget = data;`

```
           if(!$scope.$$phase)
            {
                $scope.$digest();
            }
```

Please let me know if it works good.